# how to duplicate a form using alpine.js

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

Given a form with a couple of `input form fields`, for example:

(the style is based on `tailwindcss` if it plays a role)

```
<div>
  <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
    <div class="md:col-span-1">
      <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
        <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Profile</h3>
        <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
          This information will be displayed publicly so be careful what you share.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
      <form action="#" method="POST">
        <div class="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
          <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white space-y-6 sm:p-6">

            <!-- todo: duplicate the input form fields  -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
              <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                <label for="first_name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" autocomplete="given-name" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
              </div>

              <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                <label for="last_name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" autocomplete="family-name" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
            <button type="button" @click="duplicate(idx)" class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
              +
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to add dynamically / duplicate the two form fields (first name, last name) when the end user clicks on the `+` button (`duplicate(idx)` function), using `alpine.js` ?